# Jquery DataTable Filter Sorting

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I try to **sort**(sorting filter) datas in jquery by using **datatable**.

I have below code however there is no **feature** like **sorting** in column.

Where i miss Why below code does not work ?

```
$('#sample_1').dataTable().ColumnFilter({
       sPlaceHolder: "head: before",
       aoColumns: [{ type: "date-range" },
                   { type: "text" },
                   { type: "text" }
                  ]
       });
});
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried the documentation? (http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/basic_init/table_sorting.html)

Comment: sorting is a default feature in datatables. There must be something wrong with your html. Are you sure 3 columns(only) are in your html? Maybe a screen shot, or your html table before initialization will help us a lot to determine the problem